# Return CARTO Map in Flask

Tags: python, carto, flask

I am developing an app with Flask and Cartoframes.
How return Map in template?
My code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from cartoframes.auth import set_default_credentials
from cartoframes.viz import Map, Layer, color_category_style
from cartoframes.viz import popup_element
from cartoframes import read_carto

app = Flask(__name__)
set_default_credentials('creds.json')
gdf = read_carto('table_1')

def create_map(points):
    layer = Layer(
        points,
        color_category_style('type'),
        title="Type of organization",
        popup_hover=[
            popup_element('address', 'Address')
        ],
        popup_click=[
        popup_element('company', 'Company'),
        popup_element('phone', 'phone'),
        popup_element('email', 'email'),
        popup_element('site', 'site'),
    ],
    encode_data=False
)
my_map = Map(layer)
return my_map


@app.route("/index")
@app.route("/")
def index():

    created_map=create_map(gdf)
    return render_template('index.html',map =created_map)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But  this does not work:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, CARTOframes does only work in a (collab, jupyter) notebook environment. You would need to use any of their Python or JS SDKs.